# Big numbers Napier's location arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I have to represent this equation 2049*(M+N*100)+(M*N)*2<sup>800</sup> using John Napier's [Location Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_arithmetic) and then calculate it using the notation's characteristic.

So for example I know that 29*11 would be (2*1)(2*1)(9*1)(9*1) = 3 3 10 10 = 4 11 = 2<sup>4</sup>+ 2<sup>11</sup> = 16 + 2048 = 2064.

With that knowledge I can change most part of equation, but how can I calculate it with a big number like 2<sup>800</sup>?

Let's say M = 7 and N = 10.